# Extract object with all fields equals except specific one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I have this js object

```
[
    {
        "comparing_result": "d_sens",
        "event": "Require",
        "master_field": "type_de_donnees",
        "master_field_type": "Select",
        "operator": "=",
        "slave_field": "criticite_de_donnees",
        "slave_field_type": "Select"
    },
    {
        "comparing_result": "d_pers",
        "event": "Require",
        "master_field": "type_de_donnees",
        "master_field_type": "Select",
        "operator": "=",
        "slave_field": "criticite_de_donnees",
        "slave_field_type": "Select"
    },
    {
        "comparing_result": "d_ptry",
        "event": "Not Required",
        "master_field": "type_de_donnees",
        "master_field_type": "Select",
        "operator": "=",
        "slave_field": "criticite_de_donnees",
        "slave_field_type": "Select"
    }

]
```

and I'm trying to filter it on order to have this

```
[
    {
        "comparing_result": ["d_sens", "d_pers"],
        "event": "Require",
        "master_field": "type_de_donnees",
        "master_field_type": "Select",
        "operator": "=",
        "slave_field": "criticite_de_donnees",
        "slave_field_type": "Select"
    },
    {
        "comparing_result": "d_ptry",
        "event": "Not Required",
        "master_field": "type_de_donnees",
        "master_field_type": "Select",
        "operator": "=",
        "slave_field": "criticite_de_donnees",
        "slave_field_type": "Select"
    }
]
```

So if properties values in each element are the same,except for the comparing_result property, I need to merge them in order to obtain a merge of different comparin_result

I've tried with some filter functions but I didn't find the 'right' method to do it!
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to do something like `objArr.forEach(obj => delete obj.comparing_result)`

Comment: The expected result has `comparing_result` in it, so deleting it won't work. It seems like OP wants to group by all properties and merge `comparing_result` when the properties are the same.

Comment: The question was edited, you're right, my answer's irrelevant